# Solving Diffie–Hellman problem for low primitive root

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

What's a good way of solving the Diffie–Hellman problem when those exchanging the message have chosen a low primitive root $g$ (e.g. $g=3$)?

Of course you could brute force it but I'm interested in knowing whether there is a formula for solving it when you know $g^a \pmod{p}$ and $g^b \pmod{p}$ as well as $p$ and $g$ of course.

**Edit:** For those unfamiliar with the Diffie–Hellman problem the integers $g$ and $p$ (with $1 < g < p$ and $p$ being prime), $g^a \pmod{p}$ and $g^b \pmod{p}$ are public. The integers $a$ and $b$ are private integers and we want to calculate the secret key $s = g^{ab} \pmod{p}$.

Comment: It would be good to precisely state the Diffie-Hellman problem: Given $g$, $p$, $g^a \pmod p$ and $g^b \pmod p$, find the value of $g^{ab} \pmod p$.

Comment: What do you mean by "low"? Do you mean small as an integer, e.g. g=2, 3, 5, etc.?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I'll add it.

Comment: @GregS Yes, I'm thinking of an integer less than 10

Comment: One (horribly inefficient) way would be to take the discrete logarithms of both $g^a \mod p$ and $g^b \mod p$ (using e.g. Pollard ρ), multiply a and b, and perform modular exponentiation again with the product as the exponent.

Comment: It has been my understanding that there are methods (Pollard factorization?) which are faster on average for small g and so I have always chosen a random and verified g.  Sorry that I can't remember why.

Comment: @Dan Brumleve, as far as I know there is no known algorithm that can take advantage of small generators for solving the Diffie-Hellman problem more efficiently. However, there are some other DL based cryptosystems, where choosing a small generator may indeed be a problem. One such example is the Elgamal signature scheme. An attack here is described in the "Handbook of applied cryptography" (Chapter 11, Note 11.67).

Answer (score 3):

Diffie–Hellman is a protocol for data exchange with no shared secret.

It already assumes that you know $p$, $g$, $g^a\pmod{p}$ and $g^b\pmod{p}$.

So under the protocol assumptions, the answer to your question is no.

---

**Public Information:**

- Prime number $p$
- Generator $g\in{Z^*_p}$

**Protocol:**

[image]

**Advantage of Alice and Bob over Eve:**

- Alice and Bob can easily compute $k=g^{ab}$
- Eve intercepts $g^a$ and $g^b$, but cannot easily compute $g^{ab}$

**Terminology:**

[image]

**Assumptions:**

- $DLOG$ holds in the Diffie-Hellman protocol
- $CDH$ holds in the Diffie-Hellman protocol

Of course, if either one of these assumptions is false, then the answer to your question is yes.

---

**Prove $CDH \implies DLOG$:**

- $\neg DLOG \implies$ Given $g$ and $g^x$, it’s easy to compute $x$
- So given $g$, $g^a$ and $g^b$, one can easily compute $a$ and $b$, and then compute $g^{ab}$
- Conclusion: $\neg DLOG \implies \neg CDH$

**Prove $DDH \implies CDH$:**

- $\neg CDH \implies$ Given $g$, $g^x$ and $g^y$, it’s easy to compute $g^{xy}$
- So given $g$, $g^a$, $g^b$ and $g^c$, one can easily compute $g^{ab}$, and then compare it with $g^c$
- Conclusion: $\neg CDH \implies \neg DDH$

**Prove $DDH$ does not hold in the Diffie-Hellman protocol:**

- For random $a,b\in{Z_p}:ab$ is even with probability $\frac{3}{4} \implies g^{ab}\in{QR_p}$ with probability $\frac{3}{4}$
- For random $c\in{Z_p}:c$ is even with probability $\frac{1}{2} \implies g^{c}\in{QR_p}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$
- Solution:

  - Prime numbers $p$ and $q$, s.t, $p=2q+1$
  - Generator $g\in{QR_p}$ (instead of $g\in{Z^*_p}$)
- Example:

  - $p=11 , Z^*_p = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$
  - $q=5  , QR_p  = \{1,3,4,5,9\}           $

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is what is known as the [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem. The reason Diffie-Hellman is good for large numbers is that solving the discrete logarithm, in general, is **hard**. It there was a formula we knew for it, this wouldn't be good for DH-cryptography. I will copy the rest of my answer from **Accipitridae**:

> However, there are some other DL based cryptosystems, where choosing a small generator may indeed be a problem. One such example is the Elgamal signature scheme. An attack here is described in the "Handbook of applied cryptography" (Chapter 11, Note 11.67).